# How do you formally state the axiom of constructibility?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

The [Axiom of Constructibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_constructibility) states every set is [constructible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe).

My question is, how would one formally state this, since it seems to involve quite a bit of metamathematics? In particular, if one wanted to add this as an axiom to, say, ZFC, how would you state it?

Comment: Is there any particular step of the definition of "constructible" on Wikipedia you don't know how to formalize?

Comment: The expression would be quite long and entirely unreadable, but it is definitely doable.

Comment: @EricWofsey Definability, and fitting it all into a single axiom.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Recall that $x\in L$ if and only if there is some $\alpha$ such that $x\in L_\alpha$. And that is exactly the content of the axiom $V=L$:

> For every $x$, there exists an ordinal $\alpha$ such that $x\in L_\alpha$.

But wait, what is $L_\alpha$ anyway? Ah, well, luckily, it is the unique set $X$ such that there exists a function $f$ with domain $\alpha+1$, that $f(0)=\varnothing$, $f(\gamma+1)$ is the definable subsets of $f(\gamma)$, if $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal then $f(\gamma)=\bigcup\{f(\beta)\mid\beta<\gamma\}$, and $X=f(\alpha)$.

Note that "definable subsets" is an internal notion, which requires a very long definition, which essentially establishes a large chunk of first-order logic as internalized by $\sf ZF$. But it is certainly the internal version of "definable" we are talking about here, and this is important.

So what would a complete write up of this axiom include? A rudimentary definition of first-order logic and what it means for a set to be definable; then the definition of the function $\alpha\mapsto L_\alpha$; then the statement that for every $x$, there is some $\alpha$ such that $x\in L_\alpha$. We leave writing something like this in full as an exercise to the masochistic reader.

Comment: how does this axiom of constructibility work in practice ? if I consider a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, does it have to be definable ?

Comment: I entirely don't understand your question. Also definable in *what structure*? In what language? Everything is definable *somewhere*. See also http://karagila.org/2015/name-that-number/

Comment: there is an obvious concept of definable subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, I don't think I need to formalize it, and I'm asking how in practice the axiom of constructibility (in ZFC..) is a restriction for the definability of $X$ a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: No. There is no "obvious concept" here. And yes, you do need to formalize it for me to give you an accurate answer.

Comment: I'm not asking for an accurate answer, only some intuition

Comment: @user1952009 well, we are adding an axiom, not removing one. Therefore, things that existed before still exist.

Comment: @user1952009: Sorry, unless I can understand your question, I can't give you any intuition. Not to mention that "definable subset" is rife with subtleties that cause a lot of people to make a lot of wrong claims (e.g. "only countably many subsets of $\Bbb N$ are definable").

Comment: @PyRulez: Not quite right, though, since $V=L$ implies that some sets do not exist in the universe. There are philosophical conundrums and dilemmas as to whether or not you've increased your universe or shrunk it by adding $V=L$, and I don't want to get into them.

Comment: I'd start from the set of computable functions $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, and I'd add to it iteratively those of the form $f(n)=\exists k\in \mathbb{N},g(k)$ and the computable functions of those. So I'd make the computable functions closed for some (finite) first-order logic operation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_set seems to say it is a good idea to make it closed also for the second ($n$th ?) order logic formulas, but then it becomes way too complicated for me. How the axiom of construtibility is related with this "closure of the computable functions" ?

Comment: @user1952009: Since $\sf ZF$ proves there are uncountably many sets of natural numbers, it proves there are sets which are not arithmetic, namely cannot be defined over $\Bbb N$ ***in the language of arithmetic***. Since $V=L$ is consistent with $\sf ZF$, it cannot disprove that there are sets which are not arithmetic.

Comment: is it the "$\gamma$ is a limit ordinal" part of what you wrote in your answer ?

Comment: @user1952009: I have no idea what the two questions have in common. The definition of the constructible hierarchy is done by transfinite recursion, and the treatment of a limit ordinal case is part of the transfinite recursion. It sounds like you have a knowledge gap that you're trying to bridge here, and that's commendable, but wrong. You should instead study set theory properly. Again, this is a topic rife with subtleties, and trying to "get the general idea" over comments online is not the right way to get the general idea at all.

Comment: I know what is transfinite induction/recursion. And in set theory courses, nowhere definability is mentioned, as far as I know. My question is very simple : how an un-definable subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is constructible..

Comment: @user1952009: Because we take definable subsets, repeatedly. So we have more and more access to more and more subsets over time.

Comment: @user1952009: At this point, you might as well grasp the concept of definability first before trying to think about Godel's L. Suppose you just look at all definable sets over ZF (using no parameters), meaning you take all $1$-place sentence $φ$ such that $ZF \vdash \exists! x\ ( φ(x) )$. Then you have countably many formulae, and so there are only countably many definable sets over ZF. But ZF proves that there are uncountably many sets of naturals, and so in every model $M$ of ZF there will be at least one set in $M$ that is not definable over ZF.

Comment: @user21820: How do you reconcile this with pointwise definable models? The answer is that you need to separate "countably many formulae" which is a statement in the meta-theory, and that ZF might not *prove* the uniqueness of each definition, it will just be the case in the specific model.

Comment: Oops I made a silly mistake. Sorry. Let me state it again: In every model $M$ of ZF that has uncountably many sets (after all this is the kind of model of ZF that we are interested in), there will be at least one set in $M$ that is not definable over ZF. @user1952009: Please note that my previous comment was erroneous but I'm leaving both to show the slight distinction.