# Can we formulate V=L inside ZF?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Is V=L a metatheory statement, or can this statement be formulated inside ZF?

Comment: not sure why this was put on hold as unclear. It's a bit brief, but seems to ask a clear question.

Comment: This is a very clear question, but it is in fact a duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839352/how-do-you-formally-state-the-axiom-of-constructibility

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although not obvious, it can indeed be formulated in the language of set theory *(incidentally, the same is true of $V=HOD$ - this requires a trick, since the obvious approach seems to require a definition of truth in $V$)*. The details are covered carefully in [Kunen's text](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444868399).

*EDIT: As per Eric Wofsey's comment, expressing "$V=L$" in the language of set theory amounts to defining $L$ in the language of set theory (since then we just say "all sets are in $L$"), and the latter is necessary to even metatheoretically define $L^M$ for illfounded models $M$ (how do you perform a recursive definition along an ill-founded ordering, unless you're doing it inside some smaller model that things the ordering is well-founded?). So the sequence of ideas here is: we first define $L^N$ for well-founded $N$ in the metatheory, then show how to define $L^M$ for general (= possibly ill-founded) models, and this in fact subsumes the task of expressing "$V=L$" in the language of set theory.*

One approach is straightforward:

- First, show that the formula "$x$ is a definable subset of $y$" (where $x\subseteq y$, $y$ is a transitive set, and we're viewing $y$ as an $\{\in\}$-structure) is expressible in the language of set theory. The key point is that since $y$ is a set, we can talk about Skolem functions over $y$; this doesn't work for trying to define definability with respect to $V$.
- With that in hand, we can now define an **$L$-sequence** to be a sequence indexed by some ordinal whose $0$th term is $\emptyset$, whose limit terms are given by unions, and whose successor terms are given by definable powersets. "$V=L$" is then shorthand for "Every set is a member of some term of some $L$-sequence."

There is also - surprisingly, in my opinion - a purely combinatorial approach discovered by Godel: that $L$ is the closure of the ordinals under [a small list of basic operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_operation). It should be clear that $L$ contains the closure of the ordinals under these operations, since they're definable; the converse is nontrivial but true. So this gives another way to express "$V=L$" in the language of set theory.

*Of course, ultimately the metatheory rears its head when we try to argue that the formalizations of "$V=L$" in the language of set theory actually match the metatheoretic statement "$V=L$," but it's pretty clear they do. In particular, a reasonable metatheory can prove that a well-founded $M\models ZFC$ satisfies $V=L$ iff $M=L^M$, where $L^M$ is defined in the metatheory as usual.*

Comment: @hardmath I'm not sure what you're getting at. There are lots of propositions which claim something about all sets (e.g. the axiom of regularity), so that's not an issue.

Comment: @hardmath That's not true. The axiom of regularity, for example, is (in the presence of Replacement) just "$V=WF$." Talking about $V$ is easy since it's a definable class, we just can't *quantify over* classes. There's no problem here.

Comment: The *syntax* of ZF does not admit proper classes.  I'm sure you know that, so I'm not sure what to make of your discussion of (for example) the axiom of regularity.  Of course there are statements in ZF that apply to all sets, but this does not reify the proper class $V$.

Comment: I feel this answer makes this sound harder than it is.  All the complicated stuff you describe is just the work involved in defining $L$ in the first place (which must be done internally, not in the metatheory, since for instance it involves transfinite recursion over the _internal_ ordinals).  So, if you know what $L$ even means, you already know all of that, and formulating $V=L$ is just a matter of saying "every set is in $L$".

Comment: @EricWofsey I disagree somewhat - at the informal level, we define $L$ with respect to the "true" model, and assume that its ordinals are well-founded. Put another way, implicit in the OP's question is "Why does $L^M$ make sense, even if $M$ is ill-founded?"

Comment: @hardmath I'm not sure where I reified any proper classes. My point is that referencing $V$ simply isn't problematic at all, any more than referencing $L$ or any other definable proper class, since what we're really doing is just using abbreviations for specific formulas. If you prefer, "$V=L$" is shorthand for "Every set is constructible." I'm not sure what the issue is here?

Comment: @hardmath “V=WF” is just $\forall x \exists \alpha (x\in V_\alpha),$ which is (equivalent over ZF$^-$ to) the axiom of regularity. Similarly, “V=L” is $\forall x \exists \alpha (x\in L_\alpha).$ No reference to any proper classes.

Comment: @hardmath Really I guess to make full contact with class notation, V=WF unpacks literally to $\forall x (x=x \leftrightarrow \exists \alpha (x\in V_\alpha)),$ but that's logically equivalent to the above.